# Is it a good practice to create a ClassCollection of another Class?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, programming-practices, class-design, patterns-and-practices

Lets says I have a `Car`class:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Engine { get; set; }
    public string Seat { get; set; }
    public string Tires { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say we're making a system about a parking lot, I'm going to use a lot of the `Car` class, so we make a `CarCollection` class, it may has a few aditionals methods like `FindCarByModel`:

```
public class CarCollection
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Car FindCarByModel(string model)
    {
        // code here
        return new Car();
    }
}
```

If I'm making a class `ParkingLot`, what's the best practice?

**Option #1:**

```
public class ParkingLot
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    //some other properties
}
```

**Option #2:**

```
public class ParkingLot
{
    public CarCollection Cars { get; set; }
    //some other properties
}
```

Is it even a good practice to create a `ClassCollection` of another `Class`?

Comment: What benefit do you perceive in passing a `CarCollection` rather than a `List<Car>` around? Especially given that CarCollection doesn't extend the backing List class, or even implement the Collection interface (I'm sure that C# has similar things).

Comment: List<T> already implements IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable... Besides, I could use Linq...

Comment: But `public class CarCollection` doesn't implement IList or ICollection, etc... thus you can't pass it to something that is ok with a list.  It claims as part of its name that it is a collection, but doesn't implement any of those methods.

Comment: being a 6 year old question I see no-one has mentioned that this is a common practice in DDD. Any collection should be abstracted into a custom collection. For example say you wanted to calculate the value of a group of cars. Where would you put that logic? in a service? Or in DDD you would have a `CarColection` with a `TotalTradeValue` property on it. DDD isn't the only way to design systems, just pointing it out as an option.

Comment: Exactly, These things are actually aggregate roots as suggested in DDD, Only thing is DDD would probably not recommend you to call it a car collection. Rather use some names like Parking Lot, or Work Area etc.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Prior to generics in .NET, it was common practice to create 'typed' collections so you would have `class CarCollection` etc for every type you needed to group. In .NET 2.0 with the introduction of Generics, a new class `List<T>` was introduced which saves you having to create `CarCollection` etc as you can create `List<Car>`.

Most of the time, you will find that `List<T>` is sufficient for your purposes, however there may be times that you want to have specific behaviour in your collection, if you believe this to be the case, you have a couple of options:

- Create a class which encapsulates `List<T>` for example `public class CarCollection { private List<Car> cars = new List<Car>(); public void Add(Car car) { this.cars.Add(car); }}`
- Create a custom collection `public class CarCollection : CollectionBase<Car> {}`

If you go for the encapsulation approach, you should at minimum expose the enumerator so you would declare it as follows:

```
public class CarCollection : IEnumerable<Car>
{
    private List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

    public IEnumerator<Car> GetEnumerator() { return this.cars.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

Without doing that, you can't do a `foreach` over the collection.

Some reasons you might want to create a custom collection are:

- You don't want to fully expose all the methods in `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`
- You want to perform additional actions upon adding or removing an item from the collection

Is it good practice? well that depends on *why* you are doing it, if it is for example one of the reasons I have listed above then yes.

Microsoft do it quite regularly, here are some fairly recent examples:

- [System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpFilterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.httpfiltercollection%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
- [System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderProviderCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderprovidercollection%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

As for your `FindBy` methods, I would be tempted to put them in extension methods so that they can be used against any collection containing cars:

```
public static class CarLookupQueries
{
    public static Car FindByLicencePlate(this IEnumerable<Car> source, string licencePlate)
    {
        return source.SingleOrDefault(c => c.LicencePlate == licencePlate);
    }

    ...
}
```

This separates the concern of querying the collection from the class which stores the cars.

Comment: Following this approach, I could even dismiss the `ClassCollection` even for the add, delete, update methods, by adding a new `CarCRUD` which will encapsulate all this methods...

Comment: @Luis I wouldn't recommend the `CarCRUD` extension as enforcing its use would be difficult, the advantage to putting the custom crud logic in the collection class is that there is no way to bypass it. Additionally, you may not actually care about the Find logic in the core assembly where `Car` etc are declared, that might be a UI only activity.

Comment: Just as a note from MSDN: "We don't recommend that you use the CollectionBase class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic Collection<T> class." - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.collectionbase?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Answer (score 9):

No. The creation of `XXXCollection` classes pretty much fell out of style with the advent of generics in .NET 2.0. In fact, there is the nifty `Cast<T>()` LINQ extension that folks use these days to get stuff out of those custom formats.

Comment: What about the custom methods we could have inside that `ClassCollection`? is it a good practice to put them on the main `Class`?

Comment: I believe that falls under the software development mantra of "it depends". If you're talking about, for example, your `FindCarByModel` method, that makes sense as a method on your repository, which is slightly more complex than just a `Car` collection.

Answer (score 2):

It's often handy to have domain-oriented methods to find / slice collections, as in the FindByCarModel example above, but there's no need to resort to creating wrapper collection classes. In this situation I will now typically create a set of extension methods.

```
public static class CarExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Car> ByModel(this IEnumerable<Car> cars, string model)
    {
        return cars.Where(car => car.Model == model);
    }
}
```

You add as many filter or utility methods to that class as you like, and you can use them anywhere you have `IEnumerable<Car>`, which includes anything `ICollection<Car>`, arrays of `Car`, `IList<Car>` etc.

Since our persistence solution has a LINQ provider, I'll frequently also create similar filter methods that operate on and return `IQueryable<T>`, so we can apply these operations to the repository too.

The idiom of .NET (well, C#) has changed a lot since 1.1. Maintaining custom collection classes is a pain, and you gain little from inheriting from `CollectionBase<T>` that you don't get with the extension method solution if all you need is domain-specific filter and selector methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only reason to create a special class for holding a collection of other items should be when you add something of value to it, something more than just encapsulate/inherit from an instance of `IList` or another type of collection.

For example, in your case, adding a function that would return sublists of cars parked on even/uneven lot spaces... And even then... maybe only if it's often reused, because if it only takes one line with a nice LinQ function and is used only once, what's the point ? [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) !

Now, if you plan to offer a lot of sorting/finding methods, then yes, I think this could be useful because this is where they should belong, in that special collection class. This is also a good way for "hiding" the complexities of some "find" queries or whatever you could do in a sorting/finding method.

Comment: Even tho, I think I could include those methods on the main `Class`

Comment: Yes, indeed... you can

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to go with the following option, so you can add you method to the collection and use the advantage of list.

```
public class CarCollection:List<Car>
{
    public Car FindCarByModel(string model)
    {
        // code here
        return new Car();
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like C#7.0

```
public class ParkingLot
{
    public CarCollection Cars { get; set; }=new CarCollection();
    //some other properties
}
```

Or you can use it like

```
public class ParkingLot
{
   public ParkingLot()
   {
      //initial set
      Cars =new CarCollection();
   }
    public CarCollection Cars { get; set; }
    //some other properties
}
```

**-- Generic version thanks to @Bryan comment**

```
   public class MyCollection<T>:List<T> where T:class,new()
    {
        public T FindOrNew(Predicate<T> predicate)
        {
            // code here
            return Find(predicate)?? new T();
        }
       //Other Common methods
     }
```

and then you can use it

```
public class ParkingLot
{
    public MyCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }=new MyCollection<Car>();
    public MyCollection<Motor> Motors{ get; set; }=new MyCollection<Motor>();
    public MyCollection<Bike> Bikes{ get; set; }=new MyCollection<Bike>();
    //some other properties
}
```

Comment: don't inherit from List<T>

Comment: @Bryan, you right the question is not for generic collection. I'll modify my answer  for generic collection.

Comment: @WaleedAK you still did it -- don't inherit from List<T>:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Comment: @Bryan: if you read your link **When is it acceptable? When you're building a mechanism that extends the List<T> mechanism.**, So it will be fine as long as there are no additional properties